# how to access private members of one class to another

Tags: c++

In the code below, there two classes a and b. The error that i am unable to resolve is that i can't access name and time in class b using pointer ptr of type a. I know that there are other ways to access them using getters or making a friend function however this is the part of my assignment so i am instructed to do it this way. For convenience, I have commented the line that is showing error. It would be a great help if someone helps me to resolve this issue.

```
class a{
private:
    char name[12];
    char time[12];
public:
    a(){
        strcpy(name,"");
        strcpy(time,"");
    }
    void set(char *n,char *t){
        for(int i=0;n[i]!='\0' && i<12;i++){
            name[i] = n[i];
        
        }
        for(int i=0;n[i]!='\0' && i<12;i++){
            time[i] = t[i];
        
        }
    
    }
    
};


class b{
private:
    a *ptr;
    static int index;
public:
    b(){
        ptr= new a[2];
    }
    b(int size){
        index=size;
        ptr = new a[index];
    
    }
    void show(){
        for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
            cout << ptr[i].name << ", " << ptr[i].time << endl; // Error
            
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe ask your instructor for clarification, because I'm not sure why neither "write some kind of accessor" nor "make `b` a `friend` of `a`" are acceptable solutions. There _are_ other ways to do this, but I'd first double-check that your understanding of your assignment's constraints is correct.

Comment: Unrelated: You should delete dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: I have been provided with two files: one header file and one cpp file by my course instructor. Class is defined in the header file and its implementation(function's definitions) are in the cpp file.I just read my assignments instructions again right after you commented and my instructor has allowed to modify those files from which i deduce we can make getters function or friend functions. So, can you please guide me on how to use friend function in accessing private members. @Nathan Pierson

Comment: Looks like you can use `strcpy`, so you can save a lot of code in `set` by using it again.

Comment: http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html

Answer (score 1):

Private members can only be accessed in its class or with getters.
Also, you can make these members protected or public to access them successfully.

You can check [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Well since both fields are private in A you can't access them without getters in this case or making them public
As pointed out by the comment you can have B inherit form A if the fields are protected

Comment: Making `b` inherit from `a` wouldn't actually solve this. The relevant members are `private`, not `protected`.

Comment: Thank you I have updated the comment (I forgot only protected data can be accessed (y))

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions for foreign classes where you can't edit the original A class:

**A) use pointer arithmetic to access private variable:**
Create a dynamic object of A and shift the pointer to the offset of the private variable's address, then read the appropriate size.

**B) implement a class similar to A with the getters at the end:**
Create a class (A1) with exactly the same implementation, but add the getters to the end. Then create a dynamic object of A and cast it to A1.

```
A a;
A1* a1 = reinterpret_cast<A1*>(&a);
```

Then you can use the getters to access the original A private variables.

Comment: For B) since `a` is not pointing at an `A1` object, accessing `A1`'s methods on an `A` object is **undefined behavior**

Comment: Thanks, I totally messed it up. Fixed it now.

Comment: What you changed the code to is no better than what you had originally. The new code is still undefined behavior without a real `A1` object, ie by *deriving* `A1` from `A` and then constructing `A1`, eg: `class A1 : public A { ... }; A* a = new A1;`

Comment: If he can't edit the class `A`, how can he find the right offsets?

Comment: @DogaOruc this runs along the same lines as why Nathan Pierson is questioning the asker's interpretation of the assignment. When the right way to perform a task has been rejected by fiat, you should examine why. Maybe the assignment was misread. Maybe the instructor has something really sneaky in mind. Maybe the instructor doesn't actually know how to program in C++.

Comment: @DogaOruc e.g. he's got the header but can't see the implementation of the given class. These are rather dirty hacks used mainly for reverse engineering rather than good practices to follow in everyday work. But I thought I add these because the context of the usage was not clear.

Comment: Both ways are undefined behavior, there are legal trick to access private members though: [access-to-private-members-thats-easy](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html).